# Entity Framework Code-First Issues (SimpleMembership UserProfile table)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

If you've used ASP.NET MVC 4 you'll notice that the default for an Internet Application is to use the SimpleMembership provider, this is all well and good and works fine.

The issue comes with the default database generation, they have a POCO for `UserProfile` defined like so:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

.. which is then generated like this:

```
using (var context = new UsersContext())
{
    if (!context.Database.Exists())
    {
         // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
         ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
    }
}
```

This works fine, the database is generated just fine and works without issue. However, if I am to change the POCO like this and delete the database:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Only the first 2 columns are generated, `UserId` and `EmailAddress`. It works just fine code-wise (talking login/registration), but obviously none of my other user data is stored.

Am I missing something here? Surely it should generate the database based off the whole `UserProfile` object.

Comment: Looks odd. Is this repeatable? I.e. Clean and rebuild everything, doublecheck the results. Are you looking at the right Db?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Unfortunately yes, I've been driving myself mad for the past 2 days with this, I even tried attributing each column with it's own name and they're simply not there. What makes it worse is that `UserId` and `EmailAddress` (or whatever I rename these to) *are* there just fine.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Should also be worth noting that I've tried changing this table on a completely new project just as a test and it has the same issue. What I haven't tried is using Entity Framework standalone to generate the database, maybe I'll do that next, but would rather stay as aligned to the default ASP.NET MVC4 structure as possible for now..

Comment: Well, then I'm stumped, and no time to try this myself.

Comment: You need to provide your own Membership provider to control all your fields ..

Comment: @Persian. This is nothing to do with the membership provider, but to do with Entity Framework's database generation being screwy for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems I may have finally got this, and it may have just been one giant misunderstanding.

As it turns out, I was expecting `((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();` to do what it simply doesn't, which is create all of the tables in the database that don't exist, or simply update them if they do and they're different.

What actually happens is that it literally runs a `CREATE DATABASE` statement, which to me is the most useless thing ever. Unless you're working in a really strange environment, you will always have a database on the off and so it would always exist (and subsequently the table creation would never happen!), I'd rather not be giving real-world users access to create a database anyway.

Anyway, I solved my specific issue of wanting `UserProfile` (and related tables) to create the database by using the `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` initializer, and forcing an initialization like below:

```
public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
{
#if DEBUG
    Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>());
#else
    Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(null);
#endif

    try
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            if (!context.Database.Exists())
            {
                ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
            }
            context.Database.Initialize(true);
        }

        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "EmailAddress", autoCreateTables: true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
    }
}
```

.. this works and is perfect for development but is pretty useless in practice since it will literally drop the database and recreate it from scratch if the model changes. To me, this makes the whole code-first practice almost useless in it's default form and I'll probably end up reverting back to a from-DB edmx generation.

The "mystery" behind the `UserProfile` table still being created is that `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` will initialise the table if it doesn't exist based on the fields you pass into it, which is why the `EmailAddress` was created instead of `UserName`, because I had changed it in this.

Comment: You do realize that this is what EF Migrations is for, correct?  It's useless because that's not the way you migrate from one version to another.  EF has a specific use case for this.  Also, your question said you deleted the database each time, when it appears you were not actually deleting it, but expecting EF to magically change the schema for you.  Had you actually given us the correct information, we could have given you a real response.  That's why you got a lot of head scratching, because your question said you were doing things that you didn't do.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would think that something called `CreateDatabase()` didn't actually literally create a database.  It's not useless, because it's designed to create the database when it doesn't exist, which is a situation you told us was the case.

Comment: @MystereMan Yes I'm aware of this and that is exactly what my post summarized this as; a misunderstanding! It partially stemmed from other SO posts related to similar issues where it was told that 'changing the class automatically updated the tables'. The information I gave in so far as 'deleting the database' was of course incorrect as I was actually deleting the database *contents*. My confusion came from the fact that my `UserProfile` table was still being created (albeit incorrectly), but now I realise it's the `InitializeDatabaseConnection`. It's been a **very** long few weeks :)

Comment: @Rudi, whatever happened to your other fields FirstName, Surname, Country, CompanyName ? the answer makes no mention of them, were you able to create them?!

Comment: @joedotnet They still get created when you initialise the database with the correct DataContext. I'd suggest using Migrations these days though, back in 2012 they were a fairly new concept, these days it's common place. See the most upvoted answer :) Or just run `Enable-Migrations` `Add-Migration Initial` from the package manager, when your app first runs it will create the database correctly. You can then use a `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion()` initialiser for all future updates.

Answer (score 47):

1 - You need to enable migrations, prefereably with EntityFramework 5. Use `Enable-Migrations` in the NuGet package manager.

2 - Move your

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "EmailAddress", autoCreateTables: true);
```

to your Seed method in your YourMvcApp/Migrations/Configuration.cs class

```
    protected override void Seed(UsersContext context)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
            "DefaultConnection",
            "UserProfile",
            "UserId",
            "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

        if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
            Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");

        if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("lelong37"))
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
                "lelong37",
                "password",
                new {Mobile = "+19725000000", IsSmsVerified = false});

        if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser("lelong37").Contains("Administrator"))
            Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] {"lelong37"}, new[] {"Administrator"});
    }
```

Now EF5 will be in charge of creating your UserProfile table, after doing so you will call the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection to only register SimpleMembershipProvider with the already created UserProfile table, also tellling SimpleMembershipProvider which column is the UserId and UserName. I am also showing an example of how you can add Users, Roles and associating the two in your Seed method with custom UserProfile properties/fields e.g. a user's Mobile (number).

3 - Now when you run update-database from Package Manager Console, EF5 will provision your table with all your custom properties

For additional references please refer to this article with sourcecode: 
**http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/**

Comment: Not 100% what I was asking, but it's certainly 100% helpful for others who may be having the same issue! Enjoy the bounty

Comment: FYI, Moving the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection to the seed method crashes when updating the development database ("The Role Manager Feature has not been enabled" error).

Comment: rufo, you need to make sure the Web.confi is configured with RoleProvider using SimpleRoleProvider, please refer to the link in the answer post for Web.Config entries that you need to have.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. I added code to for the migrations to happen just before the "CreateDatabase" in the SimpleMembershipInitializer.

That fixed the issue for me, except that I believe that now my migrations are going to be applied in Azure regardless the setting in the publishing profile.

```
  private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<WomContext>(null);

            // forcing the application of the migrations so the users table is modified before
            // the code below tries to create it. 
            var migrations = new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<WomContext, Wom.Migrations.Configuration>();
            var context = new WomContext(); 
            migrations.InitializeDatabase(context); 

            try
            {....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have plans to make changes once the system is live and this is only happening in development and not keen to enable migrations.  Try to truncate the table __MigrationHistory.

```
truncate table __MigrationHistory
```