# Using ASP.NET Membership tables in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have a "user management portal" created in .NET 4 Web forms. The portal allows administrators to add and edit users to specific applications (new users get a randomly generated password that's encrypted with whatever web forms uses).

I want to build an MVC 4 website that authenticates to those usernames and passwords. I know that SimpleMembership is part of ASP Membership but I'm not sure how to go about using the default created website to validate against the webforms username and password. It's not so simple to just set the machine key in the web.config and change the DB to the membership DB.

So for instance:

- User A created in the web forms app with password 1234567
- User A clicks the login button on default MVC app and uses password 1234567 (MVC app defaultConnection string is set to Web form apps database)

Does anyone have any tutorials on this or able to help?

Comment: What problems do you run using classic, default ASP.NET "web forms" membership provider withing ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: Nothing I suppose. I was just hoping there was an easy way to use the MVC default login without having to copy and paste the aspx login page.

Comment: You could always copy the provider info from an MVC3 project, or from the WebForms app, since MVC is built on top of the same core...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in `SimpleMembership` you can define the "User Profile" table, however it creates its own tables for use with passwords.

For instance, you can take any Model class and annotate it with `[Table("UserProfile")]` To get `SimpleMemebrship` to use it as the profile table.

Also this answer [Entity Framework Code-First Issues (SimpleMembership UserProfile table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502004/entity-framework-code-first-issues-simplemembership-userprofile-table) helped me a lot in modifying `SimpleMemberhip` to use my tables.

I think this may be close to what you are lookign for: http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model I think this shows how to set other tables that the default for use with `SimpleMembership`

Comment: I will give this a shot but I need the applications to have the same passwords. I know if I build multiple Webform applications, I can just map to the same authentication database and set the machine key in the webconfig and it will work. Hoping to do something similar with MVC

Comment: You also have to tell MVC SImpleMembership where to find your userprofile table  `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MovieDbContext", "UserProfile", "userID", "Username", autoCreateTables: true);`

Comment: That one doesn't place nice since the default Webforms one uses a GUID and WebSecurity when you hit the .Login() expects an int

Comment: Sorry to hear it, I only really have any experience with MVC SimpleMembership, so I probably won;t be too much help. good luck though!