# New fields not added in the database Code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I was following [this](http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties) tutorial which is about moving the `SimpleMembershipProvider` to your own database with custom fields in the userprofile table. I've added some new fields in the code:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then I run the Add-Migration command. And it generates a ######.cs file that looks like this:

```
namespace MVC4SimpleMembershipCodeFirstSeedingEF5.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class test : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The up() and Down() methods have an empty body. Somehow it's not detecting the new changes (added FirstName and LastName fields) i have made.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**

I added the same fields to another table i have created, and that table did get updated in the database.

This is what Add-Migration produced:

```
namespace MVC4SimpleMembershipCodeFirstSeedingEF5.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class test : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.TestTabel", "FirstName", c => c.String());
            AddColumn("dbo.TestTabel", "LastName", c => c.String());
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.TestTabel", "LastName");
            DropColumn("dbo.TestTabel", "FirstName");
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem has been narrowed down to the userprofile table. Whats so special about this table that it can't be altered?

Comment: Duplicate question, see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502004/entity-framework-code-first-issues-simplemembership-userprofile-table

Comment: Tried them all, none of them worked.

Comment: Do you have a sample project you can post somewhere?

Comment: I created a new project and in there everything works. But i still wonder in the another project why the userprofile didn't get updated when i changed the userprofile table. Never mind, i guess.